# Indicate more clearly on screen which keyboard I'm currently using (Linux / W10)

Tags: linux, windows-10, keyboard, autohotkey

I am currently learning Greek ... I have installed the Greek Polytonic keyboard and set up a hotkey to toggle between my normal keyboard and it.

But the problem is that I am constantly having to glance down into the bottom right of my very large monitor (43") to see which keyboard is currently selected: ENG or ΕΛ?

I just wondered (whether in W10 or Linux) there is some way of making some more prominent indicator: maybe the desktop background could switch to the Greek flag or something when I'm "in Greek"? I have Autohotkey installed in W10 (and Autokey in Linux): maybe either or both of these might provide some solution?

NB Linux OS is Linux Mint 20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows, if you have a hotkey set up already you can have AutoHotkey trigger off of that (passively) and track the internal state (vs. actually detecting what the system is set to).

The initial state would have to be set (since you would be detecting toggles and not the actual state), but that could be done any number of ways to force the script to be in sync with your settings (i.e., toggle the script state without toggling the keyboard state if they aren't in sync, and then it would be in sync after that).

The output of the script could be any number of things. You could change the background, as noted. You could keep a ToolTip somewhere else on the screen (besides the lower corner where you already have a notification). You could create a GUI window that looks like a banner off to the side or on top of your screen. You could create a colored border around the screen, or a colored bar, or box, or anything that grabs your attention. You could also not program anything other than a shell command and do something via shell command if you don't want to program it in AutoHotkey. For example to change the background you could possibly do that indirectly instead of programming it (not sure how hard that would be to do natively or not).

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation using AHK. Note that this is a giant monitor (43"), and also that my approach to AHK is "empirical": I do a lot of copying of others' scripts without usually understanding fully the major subtleties of AHK.

```
#SingleInstance force

;#HotkeyModifierTimeout -1

$#space:: ; WinKey-Space: the default (I believe) for circling between different installed keyboards
If (toggle := !toggle)
{
    Send, #{space}
    Sleep, 1000
    
    SysGet, Coord, MonitorWorkArea, 1
    Gui, Margin, 25,25
    Gui, Color, Red, EEAA99
    Gui, +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -Caption
    WinSet, TransColor, EEAA99
    Gui, Add, ListBox
; ,% "w" CoordRight-600 " h" CoordBottom-500 " Disabled"
    ,% "w" 3000 " h" 1650 " Disabled"
    Gui, Show

; needed because GUI element seems to grab focus
    SetKeyDelay 30,50
    Send, {ALT DOWN}{TAB}{ALT UP}
    SetKeyDelay, 0


}
else {
    Send, #{space}
    Sleep, 1000
    
    Gui, Hide
}
return
```

In Linux... will try something similar with Autokey ... some day!

Answer (score 0):

If your Linux desktop isn't too cluttered, (and it displays the icons (.desktop files) stored in $HOME/Desktop, you can write a little shell script or other program to copy a new icon to your desktop when the Greek keyboard is active and delete it when it's not. By default, it will be displayed in the first free space on the upper left of your desktop where it will be quite visible.

I use this when I have a financial wallet unlocked. To make it simple, I have arranged the other icons on my desktop so that the upper left corner is empty and the special icon always gets placed there by default where I expect it to be.

If an icon in your panel would be more to your liking, there's an app for that. I can't seem to find it ATM, but I'll look further if you need it.